# How do you clean a pizza stone?

Tags: equipment, pizza, barbecue, pizza-stone

I have a charcoal grill (Big Green Egg) that has a ceramic insert that can be used as a heat shield or as a pizza stone.  My stone is black from drippings and smoke.  I'd like to cook some pizza on it, but I'm not sure what I should do to clean it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perfect.  Sounds like your pizza stone is nicely seasoned.  Scrub it with your stiffest brush, rinse with water, no soap, done.  If you're paranoid about germs, cook *it* before cooking *on it*.  Throw it in the oven at a few hundred degrees, for 15 minutes or so.

Ideally, you're supposed to heat the stone (thus sterilizing it) before slapping the pizza upon it anyway (although that requires a [pizza peel](http://www.akitchen.com/store/pizzapeels.html)).

Comment: The other reason you should pre-heat the stone is to get it nice and hot so the crust cooks rapidly.

Comment: My pizza stones explicitly say to **never** use water on them, as it can cause them to shatter in the oven. The other safety option is to put them in a cold oven, and let them come to temperature so any trapped moisture escapes gradually.

Comment: @Cinque: We also learned a hard lesson when we got our first stone.  A pizza should *not* be the first thing you cook on it.  The dough will fuse to the stone and you will need a chisel to remove it.  Season the thing.  Coat it with oil and bake it, cook a few strips of bacon on it the first few times you use it, etc.  Anything but a pie until it is properly seasoned.  And yes, even when it's seasoned, coat it with cornmeal.

Answer (score 8):

I concur with all of the people above that the black burned on parts aren't at all a problem.

However if you want that buff color back, I got it back on one of mine accidentally.  I had a pizza stone that basically lived in my electric oven. During some holiday or another I stuffed it under the lower burner of the oven, and forgot it.

Later I ran the electric oven self cleaning cycle.  When I opened the oven I was shocked to see a big buff colored disk in the bottom of the oven! It had been black for so long I hadn't seen it when I pulled out the thermometer before cleaning the cycle and had forgotten it was down there.

I don't know that it won't break your Big Green Egg Plate Setter.  I use the aforementioned pizza stone on top of mine to keep the BGE part cleaner.

I have used this technique a few times to clean up pizza stones others thought were "ruined' or "finally seasoned."  But with an Egg part I suppose I would worry that it might break, and I would have to replace it. Pizza stones are much cheaper than Big Green Egg parts.

Comment: I second this.  The self-clean on my oven cleaned up all the caked on stuff off the stone and turned it to fine white powder.  Anything remaining is assuredly inert.

Answer (score 6):

As long as the black stuff won't rub off on the pizza, blackness shouldn't matter.

You should probably heat it for a while to burn off any rancid fat that has been sitting on it since you last used your grill. After its cool, a putty knife and a Brillo pad should clean it up enough.

Answer (score 6):

I scrape any crusted-on stuff (like pizza cheese) then rinse with water to get any soot off.

Never use soap on a pizza stone - they're porous, so it'll pick up a soapy taste that'll take forever to get out. Nothing wrong with it turning black - it's just becoming seasoned.

Answer (score 4):

I've had many disasters on my stone.  I used to freak out and would spend a lot of time trying to clean it.

All you need to do is scrape off the crusted on dough/cheese once the stone has heated off.  The rest will burn away next time you heat it up.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I prefer putting it in an oven and using the self-cleaning function when there is a fewer amount of oil or baked staple foods stuck on the surface of a pizza stone. You can also use a pizza **[scrubber brush](https://foodgear.org/how-to-clean-a-pizza-stone/)**. Wash with baking soda.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I've removed that link; it was a little too much like spam for our community.